# Connection reset issue while connecting to MS SQL Server (HA, Always On) from Java docker container

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, mssql-jdbc

Need help resolving the below issue.

**Issue** :
Getting connection reset issue while connecting to the always On MS SQL server from standalone java application deployed in java docker container.

**Note** : Stand alone application is working fine from windows but not working from docker image deployed on linux.

**Java code** in stand alone App :

```
public class SQLDatabaseConnection {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionUrl =
            "jdbc:sqlserver://SXXXXXXX05E:49001;"
                    + "database=AdventureWorks;"
                    + "user=yourusername@yourserver;"
                    + "password=yourpassword;"
                    + "loginTimeout=30;"
                    + "multisubnetfailover=true";
                    
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);) {
             // Code here.
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Driver version**: : mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar

**Docker Java base image** : openjdk 8. Java docker container is deployed on linux node using kubernetes.

SQL server listener(SXXXXXXX05E) (always on) has two IP addreses-> 10.100.200.111 – offline and 10.100.200.123 is online

**Observations** : with MultisubnetfailOver=true and timeout as 30 secs , it is trying to connect 3 times.

The main issue I am seeing is:
When two threads are launched to get connection, socket connector for offline IP address results getting as SUCCESS (see ->The socket of the following thread has been chosen:SocketConnector:9) then immediately getting connection reset. I
I thought offline IP address should throw timeout and only socket connector with Active IP should be choosen.

Please correct me if I am wrong in my assumptions and help me in fixing the issue.

**Log**
Failed Scenario :

```
[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 created by (SQLServerDriver:1)

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 Start time: 1590790973388 Time out time: 1590791003388 Timeout Unit Interval: 2400

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 This attempt server name: SXXXXXXX05E port: 49001 InstanceName: null useParallel: true

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 This attempt endtime: 1590790975788

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 This attempt No: 0

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 Connecting with server: SXXXXXXX05E port: 49001 Timeout slice: 2400 Timeout Full: 30

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3): Opening TCP socket...

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) Total no of InetAddresses: 2. They are: SXXXXXXX05E /10.100.200.111;SXXXXXXX05E /10.100.200.123;

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3))Using Threading with timeout:2400

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) TimeRemaining:2400; Result:UNKNOWN; Max. open thread count: 2; Current open thread count:0

[pool-6-thread-1] c.m.s.j.i.SocketConnector : SocketConnector:9(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3))) connecting to InetSocketAddress:SXXXXXXX05E /10.100.200.111:49001 with timeout:2400

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketConnector : SocketConnector:10(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3))) connecting to InetSocketAddress:SXXXXXXX05E /10.100.200.123:49001 with timeout:2400

[pool-6-thread-1] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread is waiting for socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:9(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-1] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread acquired socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:9(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-1] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The socket of the following thread has been chosen:SocketConnector:9(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-1] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread is waiting for parentThreadLock:SocketConnector:9(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread is waiting for socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:10(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-1] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread acquired parentThreadLock:SocketConnector:9(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-1] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread released parentThreadLock and notified the parent thread:SocketConnector:9(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-1] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread released socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:9(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread acquired socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:10(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread is waiting for parentThreadLock:SocketConnector:10(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread acquired parentThreadLock:SocketConnector:10(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread released parentThreadLock and notified the parent thread:SocketConnector:10(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread released socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:10(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) The parent thread wokeup.

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) TimeRemaining:2398; Result:SUCCESS; Max. open thread count: 2; Current open thread count:0

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)): Closing TCP socket:Socket[addr=SXXXXXXX05E /10.100.200.123,port=49001,localport=36682]

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: d9091629-33ce-4034-8dcc-bc86a2da0ee6 Requesting encryption level:OFF

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3) read failed:Connection reset

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerException : *** SQLException:ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: d9091629-33ce-4034-8dcc-bc86a2da0ee6 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset ClientCon

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3): Closing TCP socket...

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: d9091629-33ce-4034-8dcc-bc86a2da0ee6 Prelogin error: host SXXXXXXX05E port 49001 Error reading prelogin response: Connection

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3): Closing TCP socket...

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: d9091629-33ce-4034-8dcc-bc86a2da0ee6 sleeping milisec: 100

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 This attempt server name: SXXXXXXX05E port: 49001 InstanceName: null useParallel: true

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 This attempt endtime: 1590790988398

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 This attempt No: 1

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 Connecting with server: SXXXXXXX05E port: 49001 Timeout slice: 4800 Timeout Full: 30

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3): Opening TCP socket...

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) Total no of InetAddresses: 2. They are: SXXXXXXX05E /10.100.200.111;SXXXXXXX05E /10.100.200.123;

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3))Using Threading with timeout:4800

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) TimeRemaining:4800; Result:UNKNOWN; Max. open thread count: 2; Current open thread count:0

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketConnector : SocketConnector:25(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3))) connecting to InetSocketAddress:SXXXXXXX05E /10.100.200.111:49001 with timeout:4800

[pool-6-thread-1] c.m.s.j.i.SocketConnector : SocketConnector:26(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3))) connecting to InetSocketAddress:SXXXXXXX05E /10.100.200.123:49001 with timeout:4800

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread is waiting for socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:25(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread acquired socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:25(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The socket of the following thread has been chosen:SocketConnector:25(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread is waiting for parentThreadLock:SocketConnector:25(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread acquired parentThreadLock:SocketConnector:25(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread released parentThreadLock and notified the parent thread:SocketConnector:25(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread released socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:25(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) The parent thread wokeup.

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) TimeRemaining:4800; Result:SUCCESS; Max. open thread count: 2; Current open thread count:1

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)): Closing TCP socket:Socket[addr=SXXXXXXX05E /10.100.200.123,port=49001,localport=37168]

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: 545d8dc6-dcd8-41f5-97b2-f85523cd92c1 Requesting encryption level:OFF

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3) read failed:Connection reset

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerException : *** SQLException:ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: 545d8dc6-dcd8-41f5-97b2-f85523cd92c1 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset ClientCo

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3): Closing TCP socket...

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: 545d8dc6-dcd8-41f5-97b2-f85523cd92c1 Prelogin error: host SXXXXXXX05E port 49001 Error reading prelogin response: Connection

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3): Closing TCP socket...

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: 545d8dc6-dcd8-41f5-97b2-f85523cd92c1 sleeping milisec: 200

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 This attempt server name: SXXXXXXX05E port: 49001 InstanceName: null useParallel: true

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 This attempt endtime: 1590791001001

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 This attempt No: 2

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 Connecting with server: SXXXXXXX05E port: 49001 Timeout slice: 7199 Timeout Full: 30

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3): Opening TCP socket...

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) Total no of InetAddresses: 2. They are: SXXXXXXX05E/10.100.200.111;SXXXXXXX05E/10.100.200.123;

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3))Using Threading with timeout:7199

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) TimeRemaining:7199; Result:UNKNOWN; Max. open thread count: 2; Current open thread count:0

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketConnector : SocketConnector:43(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3))) connecting to InetSocketAddress:SXXXXXXX05E/10.100.200.111:49001 with timeout:7199

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread is waiting for socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:43(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread acquired socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:43(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The socket of the following thread has been chosen:SocketConnector:43(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread is waiting for parentThreadLock:SocketConnector:43(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread acquired parentThreadLock:SocketConnector:43(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread released parentThreadLock and notified the parent thread:SocketConnector:43(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-2] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : The following child thread released socketFinderLock:SocketConnector:43(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)))

[pool-6-thread-1] c.m.s.j.i.SocketConnector : SocketConnector:44(SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3))) connecting to InetSocketAddress:SXXXXXXX05E/10.100.200.123:49001 with timeout:7199

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) The parent thread wokeup.

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)) TimeRemaining:7198; Result:SUCCESS; Max. open thread count: 2; Current open thread count:0

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SocketFinder : SocketFinder(TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3)): Closing TCP socket:Socket[addr=SXXXXXXX05E/10.100.200.123,port=49001,localport=37676]

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: 008a03a9-ba52-409e-bade-86a06e3c291b Requesting encryption level:OFF

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3) read failed:Connection reset

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerException : *** SQLException:ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: 008a03a9-ba52-409e-bade-86a06e3c291b com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset ClientCo

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3): Closing TCP socket...

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection : ConnectionID:3 ClientConnectionId: 008a03a9-ba52-409e-bade-86a06e3c291b Prelogin error: host SXXXXXXX05E port 49001 Error reading prelogin response: Connection

[ main] c.m.s.j.i.T.Channel : TDSChannel (ConnectionID:3): Closing TCP socket...
```

All the three times Offline IP is chosen above.

Could you please help us based on the observations?